# Loading a shared library in a same directory with the executable file

Tags: cmake, shared-libraries

In Windows, an executable(`.exe`) which needs a shared library (`.dll`) can be run when the exe and dll files are in a same directory.

In Linux, even though the executable and the shared library(`.so`) are in the same directory, Linux always looks for it in the absolute directory where .so was first built, then fails to run the executable.

Setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or `RPATH` environment variable before running the executable is a ad-hoc solution, but I want to do it without setting the environment variable, and make it behaves like Windows.

How can I do it? I added [`"-rpath=$ORIGIN"` to CMakelists](https://serverfault.com/a/926072/507294) but it still fails.

For just experimenting, I made a simple program and another shared library and tried `dlopen` and it works as I wanted. However, I don't use `dlopen` for this case.

Comment: Do not move the created library *manually*. Instead, set [CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/variable/CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html) variable, so CMake will create the library at the desired place.

Comment: You've answered the question (correctly), so write your answer *as an answer* rather than an extension of the question; then accept your own answer, so that it does not persist as an unanswered question. A little more concrete detail of your CMake solution would be helpful to future readers (and incline them to upvote it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution: add `rpath` option to CMakelists.txt for the executable, **not for** the shared library.